Display error after installation
I installed Linux (Ubuntu, Xubuntu 24.04, Manjaro Xfce, Linux Mint, Fedora Workstation, Zorin and Open SUSE Leap, always the latest versions) on my iMac late 2009 (Model 10,1, Intel Core 2 Duo, 3,33 GHz, 1TB HDD, 16GB RAM, ATI Radeon HD 4670). I tried all installation types (standard, safe graphics and with proprietary drivers). Currently OS X is preinstalled in parallel to Xubuntu 24.04. I boot via the Alt key for OS X, and Xubuntu boots automatically.
During the installation the GUI is fine (good graphics and everything is shaped properly. Only newer versions of Ubuntu do not display properly.
After reboot I always see the screen split into 4 parts, and it's so bright that it's impossible to read anything.
I assume that something is wrong with the drivers for the graphics card, but I can't change them, because I can't enter the installed OS.
Closeup:

Screen split into 4 parts:


You've provided no clear specifics; this is a Ubuntu site, and whilst you do mention vague terms like 'latest' (which would imply you've tried only the 24.10 system; ie. 2024-October release), you don't actually specify, as with older hardware I tend to find older kernel stack options (selected at download time!) more beneficial, but you give no clues except latest as if your old Mac is an only recently released hardware device.  Please be specific & try to use systems that are on-topic here (ie. Ubuntu and flavors of Ubuntu).  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

If your picture is showing Xubuntu; what release did you install?  By latest I assume 24.10 (2024-October release), but for older hardware (as stated) I'd opt for an older release, particularly using the GA kernel stack of a LTS release; which flavor media provides on the ISO... the kernel stack being important as that alters kernel modules being used; kernel modules being commonly called drivers.

Hi,
I first installed ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS, 20.04.06 LTS, 18.04.06 LTS. When that did not work I tried Open Suse Leap 15.6, Manjaro xfce 24.1.1, Linux Mint xfce 22, Fedora Workstation live 41-1.4, Zorin Os 17.2 and my last try was xubuntu 24.04.01, which is currently still installed.

My iMac is from the year 2009.
Why do the graphics work perfectly fine during installation, but stop working after the first reboot. That does not make sense. Based on your comment above (guiverc) I would expect that the kernels applied during installation are the same that are active after the first reboot. So, why does the kernel stop functioning?

You need to be specific, 22.04 is a release, 22.04.5 is an installable ISO & is available using the GA kernel (5.15), HWE kernel (6.8), with kernels of 5.15, 5.19, 6.2, 6.5 & 6.8 available for 22.04 alone (and I'm not counting OEM kernel stack options).  Installers available for 22.04 are subiquity, ubiquity & calamares & whilst a calamares ISO will not install other kernel stacks to what exists on the install media; the other installers can...  Your question mentions latest where 2024-October is the latest release; your last comment doesn't even mention that latest release!

Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server & flavors can use different kernel stacks, with flavors varying on the ISO itself, eg. Xubuntu will act like Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop in regards kernel stack; which differs to both Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop & later, and all Ubuntu Server ISOs. For any release, there are many ISOs available, selected at download time, and this choice determines what gets installed; 22.04 tells you it was the 2022-April release using the year.month format used by Ubuntu, other details in ISO name give you more detail.

Well, as I said I am new to Linux. I started with Linux yesterday. The names that I gave in my comments above, I copied from the file names. I know that 22.04 equals yy.mm, at least in most of the distros I tried out. As with "kernels" I currently dont have a clue. I will try to find a godd read on this topic.
Maybe then I understand your answer.
Apart from all the kernel talk. I still dont understand why my monitor works fine during the installation, but shows a crappy picture after reboot.

Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS is a release (22.04 & .5 ISO); key detail such as what flavor you used you didn't include; eg. Server & Desktop differ in regards kernel with Server using GA, Desktop defaulting to HWE (20.04 & newer). The flavors like Xubuntu differ according to .5 point release detail (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack). Your details only mentioned the release, not being specific as to what ISO (esp. flavor detail) as many ISOs (ubiquity, subiquity, ubuntu-desktop-installer) can install different kernel stacks to that which booted at install

Okay, I will download older releases and pay more attention to the flavors and Kernels, if I can find that info. Thank you so far. I'll see how that works out.

just fyi:   but using 22.04 & the HWE detail in the link I provided; you should know how you can download 22.04 ISOs that will boot live with the 5.15 kernel (22.04 & 22.04.1 Desktop), 5.19 (Ubuntu 22.04.2 Desktop), 6.2 (22.04.3 Desktop), 6.5 (22.04.4 Desktop) & 6.8 (22.04.5 Desktop) for the same 22.04 release, and just downloading different Ubuntu Desktop ISOs (from cdimage & old-releases)..  Using a live system doesn't require install so no changes, so easy to test on difficult hardware (ie. 5 kernels for the same 22.04 Desktop release in this single example)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
